# Geolocation web service recommendations

Tags: asp.net, web-services, geolocation

Does anyone have any recommendations on geolocation web services (preferably free!)?

Planning on using it in an asp.net app, I'd heard Google might have something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) and it's very straightforward to use.  It takes some figuring out to begin with, but we were up and running using the geocoding portion in less than a day.

Comment: Make sure you read the terms, there is a limit to the number of requests a day to receive the service for free, make sure your requirements fit inside their terms.

Comment: From what I remember, you are not supposed to use Google Maps geo-location API for something that is not a Google map. So, just fetching the lat/long for an address in your app and storing that data is a no-no.

Comment: I no longer recommend Google Maps.  In less than a year, they changed APIs and broke our site twice.  We use their static maps API now, and are looking for something better.  For getting geocodes, we went away from third-party services and instead got a free database containing us geocodes, and created our own service.

Answer (score 2):

[MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com) is not free, but their SaaS (web service) offering is VERY reasonably priced.

Comment: (In case the Google Maps API doesn't work for you in terms of licensing... I'm a fan of that one too)

Comment: Yep - we're using them now - good value and dead simple - thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

I am a happy user of [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you are not allowed to cache google data either.

> [Source](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html)
>   you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to):
>   10.3 pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;

So saving the geocoded data is probably a bit of a no-no.

However-
I have not checked but highly doubt [Open Street Map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) have the same restrictions.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using these guys in the end - dead simple HTTP API:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/web_services_city_usage