# Detect/estimate country of a http-request in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I'm looking for ways to detect/estimate the **country** from which a **http-request** is coming in **ASP.NET**.
I know there are some solutions with services/country lookups but I never used one.

I'm looking for small/clean solutions.
It's for helping someone filling out a form so it does not have to be 100% accurate.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one of available web services to match an incoming request to a country.

Otherwise you may decide to grab the MaxMind database file ([GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country)), read from this file in your application and perform a match. Thus you will be independent from a third-party service, only pulling regularly updates for the database file.

Also check out similar questions:

[Geolocation web service recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247238/geolocation-web-service-recommendations)

[Know a good IP address Geolocation Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service)

Comment: I choose the GeoLite Country table. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can make a simple HTTP request to this URL:

```
http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=207.46.197.32
```

using the value of the `REMOTE_ADDR` server variable.  That will return the country and city like this:

```
Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: New York, NY
```

I use that service for a web form just as you describe.  Occasionally it doesn't know the answer, but usually it's very good (and it's free and simple 8-)

In C#, you can use [System.Net.WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create(v=vs.110).aspx) to read from the URL.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to use the REMOTE_ADDR server variable, you can be fairly certain that the IP that you recover accurately represents the nation of origin of that user. It is fairly uncommon for a user to be accessing the Internet from outside of the country that he is currently in, with a few notable exceptions, such as those who choose to surf though an anonymous proxy server, such as is discussed below. If, however, you want to get the state that a user is coming from, or authenticate the identity of a user, you're out of luck as far as any even remotely reliable method is concerned.

More info [here.](http://www.aspfaqs.com/ASPScripts/PrintFAQ.asp?FAQID=179)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'http://www.freegeoip.net/json/@(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress)',
            'type': 'GET',
            'success': function(data) {
                // for example
                if (data.country_code === "GB") {
                    ... further logic here
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Simple, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this so here's a working example (specific to France) which may be of use to someone:

```
        string userIP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        string localeAPIURL = "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=" + userIP;

        HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(localeAPIURL);
        r.Method = "Get";
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
        Stream sr = res.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(sr);

        // check response for FRANCE
        string s = sre.ReadToEnd();
        string sub = s.Substring(9, 6);
        if (sub == "FRANCE")
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://fr.mysite.com");
        }
```

Comment: hi where did you put this code? and also how can I check at login/register only