# Tracking Ip address and country name(asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net

Yesterday i saw a site in which, site is listing the ip address and country name, saying that recently visited members (a list of ip address with country name,city name). Can i know how can i track that information any reference or any code. Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287711/detect-estimate-country-of-a-http-request-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls check these questions

[Detect/estimate country of a http-request in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287711/detect-estimate-country-of-a-http-request-in-asp-net)

[How to get visitor location ( country, state and city ) using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409108/how-to-get-visitor-location-country-state-and-city-using-asp-net)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372591/how-to-get-city-country-and-country-code-for-a-particular-ip-address-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709429/IPLite-NET-Get-Country-Region-City-From-IP

in essence you need a fresh simple 900KB ip to country database to use this method from 
https://lite.ip2location.com/

in my experience old dll (2008) like https://worlddomination.codeplex.com/ did not worked and return null for countries like Iran