# How to block requests based on country region?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to block any request from some country regions.

How to do this in asp.net mvc?

Comment: If I were in your place, I'd try to do that in app server settings, not the application itself.

Comment: I am using shared hosting account so I cannot touch the server.

Comment: When implementing any suggested answer, I feel I should point out that a user could potentially get around pretty much any geographical restriction you place upon them with any number of solutions. One of the more popular solutions would be a proxy.

Comment: @Dan, can we black-list the proxy addresses? How to know whether or not the incoming request from proxy servers?

Comment: @xport. You've got no chance of doing either. There'll be too many proxies to blacklist, and users can simply create their own, and there's no way to distinguish the requests from a normal request.

Comment: @Dan, thanks. I got the point.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a HttpModule and then identify the origin of incoming request using one of the methods defined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287711/detect-estimate-country-of-a-http-request-in-asp-net) SO post to filter the requests

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the [MaxMind GeoCountry](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) database, which is also the accepted answer for the post @Cybernate recommended. I personally use the paid Region database and am quite satisfied with it.

I'm not sure about going the route of an `HttpModule` however. I personally feel better with an `ActionFilterAttribute` which overrides the `OnActionExecuting` method.