# How to integrate the acknowledgment mails in my app

Tags: java, spring, email

In my application, I am notifying the users (via SMTP) when they are called for a new project.

The notification is an email with a simple template sent with Spring.

The issue is that I Have to know if the user had read the email or not. For this I have to integrate acknowledgment mails.

Any help !!

Comment: You generally don't want to rely on read-receipts for *anything* -- [not all email applications support them, and users can disable or choose not to send them freely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954286/angularjs-how-can-i-reference-the-property-name-within-an-ng-repeat)

Comment: I want to make sure that the mail is received!! It's important to know!!

Comment: i'm not sure how email trackers work not sure they work or not ..but you can send a link with parameters.so if user click that link then surely email has opened . you can force user to click the link using some tricks

Comment: one of the approach is to put a verification link unique for every user, when a user click's it your app gets the request confirming that they viewed this mail.
To be sure that mail is received simply make an verification/activation email after account creation - then you will be sure that users provided real email addresses.

Comment: plz read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448381/tracking-email-with-php-and-image